# Node Js exit from registered event emittier

Tags: node.js, nwjs

I am using the following function code to get icon of an application, i am getting same base64 image data with all function call.

```
 iconExtractor = require('icon-extractor');
   function get_icon(appname,path) 
   {
   iconExtractor.getIcon(appname,path);
   iconExtractor.emitter.once('icon', function(data){
   console.log('Here is my context: ' + data.Context);
   console.log('Here is the path it was for: ' + data.Path);
   console.log('Here is the base64 image: ' + data.Base64ImageData);
   });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

An hour ago I also faced the same problem with icon-extractor package. 
My first intuition was also checking the event emitters. However, after checking the source code I found out that it's not related with the emitters.
In the source code, icon-extractor isn't clearing its *buffer* which piles up in each call and it calls the emitter multiple times.

You probably don't need this anymore after 2 years but for avoiding the future questions, I'll post the fixed version of the code.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events');
var fs = require('fs');
var child_process = require('child_process');
var _ = require('lodash');
var os = require('os');
var path = require('path');

var emitter = new EventEmitter();

function IconExtractor(){

  var self = this;
  var iconDataBuffer = "";

  this.emitter = new EventEmitter();
  this.iconProcess = child_process.spawn(getPlatformIconProcess(),['-x']);

  this.getIcon = function(context, path){
    var json = JSON.stringify({context: context, path: path}) + "\n";
    self.iconProcess.stdin.write(json);
  }

  this.iconProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data){

    var str = (new Buffer(data, 'utf8')).toString('utf8');

    iconDataBuffer += str;

    //Bail if we don't have a complete string to parse yet.
    if (!_.endsWith(str, '\n')){
      return;
    }

    //We might get more than one in the return, so we need to split that too.
    _.each(iconDataBuffer.split('\n'), function(buf){

      if(!buf || buf.length == 0){
        return;
      }

      try{
        self.emitter.emit('icon', JSON.parse(buf));
      } catch(ex){
        self.emitter.emit('error', ex);
      }

    });

    iconDataBuffer = "";
  });

  this.iconProcess.on('error', function(err){
    self.emitter.emit('error', err.toString());
  });

  this.iconProcess.stderr.on('data', function(err){
    self.emitter.emit('error', err.toString());
  });

  function getPlatformIconProcess(){
    if(os.type() == 'Windows_NT'){
      return path.join(__dirname,'/bin/IconExtractor.exe');
      //Do stuff here to get the icon that doesn't have the shortcut thing on it
    } else {
      throw('This platform (' + os.type() + ') is unsupported =(');
    }
  }

}

module.exports = new IconExtractor();
```

Copy the bin folder of icon-extractor module to somewhere you can reach. Create a js file with this code. So it will be something like /YourFolder/bin/ and /YourFolder/copiedFilename.js
Use it like this

```
var iconExtractor = require('./YourFolderPath/copiedFilename');
```

I hope that helps.
I was going to push that to Github repo but it's clear that he is not maintaining the module anymore.